java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The plugin specification 'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:' has a problem:
I gave an error about this.
I change dependency and versions. But, I see the same error. I don't understand. I use Selenium Webdriver, Cucumber BDD and JUnit with Java.
I have never seen this error before.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The plugin specification 'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:' has a problem:
Could not load plugin class 'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter'.
Plugin specifications should have the format of PLUGIN[:[PATH|[URI [OPTIONS]]]
Valid values for PLUGIN are: html, json, junit, message, pretty, progress, rerun, summary, teamcity, testng, timeline, unused, usage
PLUGIN can also be a fully qualified class name, allowing registration of 3rd party plugins. The 3rd party plugin must implement io.cucumber.plugin.Plugin
My Runner class and class name is always yellow underlined. (it said "Doesn't match Regex" )
`> `import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
> import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
> import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
> 
> @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
> @CucumberOptions(
> plugin = {
>                 "pretty",
>                 "html:report/default-cucumber-reports.html",
>                 "json:report/json-reports/cucumber.json",
>                 "junit:report/xml-report/cucumber.xml",
>                 "rerun:report/failed_scenarios.txt",
>                 "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"},
> monochrome = false,
> features = "src/test/resources/features",
> glue = "badgeTemp.stepDefinitions.ui",
> tags = "@x",
> dryRun = false``

------

**Please help immediately**

I want to run successfully.
I tried these 


    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>



    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber2-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>



    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber3-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>



    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>



and other things about pom.xml and Runner

